# What can cause Core Animation to produce a zombie?

Tags: iphone, ios, memory-management, core-animation

I'm getting a zombie when animating, and the Zombies instrument isn't of much help. This is what it is saying:

[image]

The code that issues the animation is a utility which takes in an animation block and passes it over to Core Animation:

[image]

I am guessing that it has to do with a view affected in the animation block that somehow goes away during animation.

I can't for the life of me figure out why Core Animation is producing the zombie. What can cause this?

Comment: It's probably not CoreAnimation but your code.

Comment: Have you checked the completion flag for a NO value? You might inadvertently do something funny in your code because the animation didn't end.

Comment: I'm not passing a completion block and the affected views don't get removed during animation.

Comment: Also I figured out Core Animation is producing zombies all over the place in my app.

Comment: Why not checking each of objects from parameters for being deallocated (by any message before the animation) ? It might be overreleased during the animation as well though.

Comment: @openfrog If you figured it out, then please share the knowledge. You're not the only one who might have this problem!

Answer (score 0):

I've used those animateWithDuration view calls many dozens of times and never had a zombie.

It sounds to me like you are handing Core Animation (or the UIView animation code) an object that is autoreleased (if you're using manual reference counting) or not strongly referenced (if you're using ARC).

Post the code that's creating the animation blocks, and also describe the life cycle of the views you are animating and of any objects that you reference in your animation block.

Pick one of your animation blocks to start with. It's likely you're making the same sort of mistake in your other animations.